# Sever fails to exit accept loop once client is done delivering message

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

Created client program using fork to read multiple files and create separate sockets. Then each socket sends the message in the file it read to the server, which uses fork to handle multiple clients. However, the sever never exits the accept loop - hence it never terminates even after all sockets on the client side are closed.

server:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include "uthash.h" //Used for building hash map

#define PORT "3400"
#define HOST "localhost"
#define MAXDATASIZE 20
#define DEPARTMENT_LEN 2
#define BACKLOG 5



int main(void){
  int sockfd, rv, child, numBytes;
  int opt = 1;
  struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
  struct sockaddr_storage their_addr; //connector's address information
  socklen_t sin_size;
  struct sigaction sa;

  char dept[MAXDATASIZE];
  double gpa;
  char dept_name[DEPARTMENT_LEN + 1];

  memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
  hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
  hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
  hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

  if((rv = getaddrinfo(HOST, PORT, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0){
    fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
    return 1;
  }

  //loop though all the results and bind to the first we can
  for(p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next){
    if((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype, p->ai_protocol)) == -1){
      perror("server: socket");
      continue; //move to next available socket
    }

    //reuse port and supress address already in use warnings
    if(setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR | SO_REUSEPORT, &opt, sizeof(opt)) == -1){
      perror("server: setsockopt");
      exit(1);
    }

    //Bind socket and local address
    if(bind(sockfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1){
      close(sockfd);
      perror("server: bind");
      continue;
    }
    break;
  }

  if(p == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "server: failed to bind\n");
    return 1;
  }

  freeaddrinfo(servinfo); //free list structure

  //Listen to client
  if(listen(sockfd, BACKLOG) == -1){
    perror("server: listen");
    exit(1);
  }

  //Reap all dead processes
  sa.sa_handler = sigchild_handler;
  sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
  sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
  if(sigaction(SIGCHLD, &sa, NULL) == -1){
    perror("sigaction");
    exit(1);
  }

  while(1){//accept() main loop
    sin_size = sizeof(their_addr);
    if((child = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &sin_size)) == -1){
      perror("server: accept");
      continue;
    }

    if(!fork()){//this is the child process
      close(sockfd);
      while(1){
        if((numBytes = recv(child, dept, MAXDATASIZE, 0)) == -1){
          perror("server: recv");
          exit(1);
        }
        dept[numBytes] = '\0';
        if(strcmp(dept, ":exit") == 0){
          printf("%s\n", dept);
          break;
        }
        else{
          //printf("%s\n", dept);
          _parse_dept(dept, dept_name, &gpa);
          //printf("%s: %.1f\n", dept_name, gpa);
          _add_dept(dept_name, gpa);
          // _print_dept();
          bzero(dept_name, (int)strlen(dept_name));
          bzero(dept, (int)strlen(dept));
        }
      }//end while
      //_print_dept();
      printf("%d\n", 2);
      close(child);
      exit(0);
    }// end fork
    printf("%d\n", 3);
    close(child); //parent doesn't need this
  }
  printf("%d\n", 4);
  //_print_dept();
  // _delete_all();
  return 0;
}
```

client:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define PORT "3400"
#define NO_DEPARTMENTS 3
#define LINE_SIZE 7
#define HOST "localhost"

//Global variable containing respective departments file name extensions
char * filenames[] = {"DepartmentA.txt", "DepartmentB.txt", "DepartmentC.txt"};
char * department_names[] = {"DepartmentA", "DepartmentB", "DepartmentC"};

int main(void){
  pid_t child_pid, wpid;
  int status = 0;
  for(int ii = 0; ii < NO_DEPARTMENTS; ii++){
    if((child_pid = fork()) == 0){
      int sockfd, rv;
      char dept_ip[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN]; //Department IP address
      unsigned int dept_port; //Department port
      struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
      struct sockaddr_in my_addr;

      memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
      hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
      hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
      if((rv = getaddrinfo(HOST, PORT, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "\ngetaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
        return 1;
      }

      //loop through all the results and connect to the first that we can find
      for(p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next){
        if((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype, p->ai_protocol)) == -1){
          close(sockfd);
          perror("client: socket");
          continue;
        }

        if(connect(sockfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1){
          close(sockfd);
          perror("client: connect");
          continue;
        }
        break;
      }
      if(p == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "client: failed to connect\n");
        return 1;
      }
      //1) Upon startup of Phase 1
      socklen_t len = sizeof(my_addr);
      getsockname(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&my_addr, &len);
      inet_ntop(AF_INET, &my_addr.sin_addr, dept_ip, sizeof(dept_ip));
      dept_port = ntohs(my_addr.sin_port);
      printf("<%s> has TCP port %d ", filenames[ii], dept_port);
      printf("and IP address %s for Phase 1\n", dept_ip);

      //2) Upon establishing a TCP connection to the admission office
      printf("<%s> is now connected to the admission office\n", filenames[ii]);


      //readfile and send contents to Addmissions office
      struct Node * fileContent = NULL;
      _readFile(&fileContent, filenames[ii]);

      struct Node * fileIter = fileContent;
      while(fileIter != NULL){
        sleep(3);
        send(sockfd, fileIter->dept, (int)strlen(fileIter->dept), 0);
        fileIter = fileIter->next;
      }
      sleep(3);
      char *ex = ":exit";
      send(sockfd, ex, (int)strlen(ex), 0);
      _freeFile(&fileContent);
      freeaddrinfo(servinfo); // free up list structure
      close(sockfd);
      exit(0); //exit for fork
    }
  }

  while ((wpid = wait(&status)) > 0);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The loop `while(1){//accept() main loop` is never "broken", left. So why do you execpt the server to end?

Comment: "*the sever never exits the accept loop*" - indeed, that's what `while(1)` means. Does this surprise you? Why did you code it that way?

Comment: @melpomene: "*Why did you code it that way?*" s/he probably didn't. This code seem to come from here: https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/multi/clientserver.html or here https://github.com/halogenandtoast/game/blob/master/server.c or ...

Comment: I wish all current "C networking tutorial" websites would get taken down already. They teach such bad practices. Code and libraries have modernised so much.

Answer (score 0):

Solved It! I had to make the queue (BACKLOG) for the accept the same amount as the number of departments, which is 3 in in this case. Then I initialized a counter to the size of the queue and decremented it each time an accept was performed. Once the counter hit zero I had the parent process wait for all the children and then break the accept loop manually.

```
if(counter > 0){
      close(child); //parent doesn't need this
      continue;
}else{
      wait(&status);
      printf("End of Phase 1 for the admission office\n");
      break;
}
```